# Send image using http

Tags: java, image, http, base64

I've got the following setup. I have to send an image over http to a browser or other device. The tricky thing about the whole it is, that I have very limited control over the http-packet creation.
I only can provide the content type field and the message body as a string.
Is there a way how I could create an http-packet containing a image with this limited configuration facilities?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have:

> Content-Type as 'application/image'
>
> data in body as binary

With your limitation as you can have only strings in body, an image cannot be sent in response.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your image to a base64 string: http://www.base64-image.de/